# findviewbyid - custom view with nested views

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have the following code and my problem is findviewbyid is returning null.

```
    <es.ric.firebase.chat.core.views.chatbox.ChatBox
        android:id="@+id/chatbox"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_text"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:hint="Escribir mensaje"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_chat"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bt_upload_picture"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_photo_black_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>




            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_circle"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </es.ric.firebase.chat.core.views.chatbox.ChatBox>
```

Java class.

```
public class ChatBox extends LinearLayout {

    enum State { MODE_MESSAGE, MODE_AUDIO, MODE_RECORDING }

    private EditText messageEditText;
    private ImageButton bt_upload_picture;
    private ImageButton sendButton;
    private WeakReference<ChatBoxListener> weak_listener;

    private State state;

    public ChatBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ChatBox(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ChatBox(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ChatBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }


    private void init(){

        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        bt_upload_picture = findViewById(R.id.bt_upload_picture);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: simply, in onAttachedToWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find the view because your view doesn't exist yet. At the point of your init function only the object is already created.

You will need to provide a globalLayoutListener which will notify you when your layout is ready. To do this implement `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`

In your init function attach the listener

```
private void init(){
    this.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
}
```

And finally call findViewById in onGlobalLayout

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout(){
    messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    bt_upload_picture = findViewById(R.id.bt_upload_picture);
    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
}
```

Comment: HI MrJM.  I'm hardly an droid expert but, surely here you simply use onAttachedToWindow (or perhaps onFinishInflate) which exist for this purpose???

Answer (score 1):

You can access the subviews after the `onFinishInflate` method is called:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
  init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I guess onAttachedToWindow would also work well.

Answer (score 0):

When your custom view constructor runs and you call `init()` the child views are not yet instantiated nor added to your `ChatBox` layout.

Having dependencies from viewgroup to specific children declared in the same layout is not a good idea anyway. You have unnecessary coupling between `ChatBox` and where it is used.

You could wait for inflation to finish but for dependency reasons I'd refactor it towards the following:

1. Pull out the child views from the layout where you're using `ChatBox` and move them to a layout of their own.
2. Make `ChatBox` inflate that layout and add the views to itself. (Use `this` as the second root view argument to `inflate()`.)
3. After that you can find the children inside your `ChatBox`.